# Window not maintaining aspect ratio on maximize in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

I have to maintain an aspect ratio of **1.36(1072/785)** for child windows in electron while resizing a window it maintains aspect ratio all the time, but once I click on **Zoom/Maximize** or **Move window to left/right side of the screen** the aspect ratio breaks(get extra width `40px` approx.) and again maintain aspect ration on resizing window. I have also gone through Electron docs: [win.setAspectRatio()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetaspectratioaspectratio-extrasize). I am using **Electron v13.1.2**, **Chromium v91.0.4472.77**, **Node v14.16.0**, **macOS Big Sur v11.2**.

Your reply is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was actually bug in electron itself checkout [electron issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/30277), fixed by [PR #30305](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/30305) .

Electron team made only single change, replaced `[window_ setAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(aspect_ratio, 1.0)]` with `[window_ setContentAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(aspect_ratio, 1.0)]` in **native_window_mac.mm** file.